# How to create an array of objects in PHP dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, object

I want to create objects with {a,b,c,d} and have an array of this objects:

[{1,1,3,5},{3,1,7,7},{3,5,7,1}]

Values a b c and d are generating in a lopp

How can I create that object? And how can I add into my array that objects?

Comment: function json_encode

Comment: sounds like json_encode and json_decode. But can you tell me a little more about what you need, the description doesn't tell us much of what you need.

Comment: I want only 1 array with n objects. All the objects have the same attributes: a,b,c,d. I think I cant use json_encode

Comment: can you show the real structure of this input `[{1,1,3,5},{3,1,7,7},{3,5,7,1}]`(cause it's invalid notation) ? What set of properties have your current objects?

Comment: What about properties of that objects?
Currently it looks like "XY" problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 11):

There is no way to write object literals in PHP like you can in JavaScript or other languages.

The easiest way you can do this in PHP is using [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)

```
// associative array
$arr = ["a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4];

// cast as object
$obj = (object) $arr;

// Or you could do it all in one line
$obj = (object) ["a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4];
```

Check it out

```
echo $obj->a; // 1
echo $obj->b; // 2
echo $obj->c; // 3
echo $obj->d; // 4
echo json_encode($obj); // {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}
```

Your loop might look something like this

```
$objects = [];
for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
  // i'll just makeup some values for a,b,c,d here since i don't know
  // how you are assigning them
  $objects[] = (object) [
    "a" => $i,
    "b" => $i * 2,
    "c" => $i * $i,
    "d" => rand()
  ];
}
print_r($objects);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 0
            [b] => 0
            [c] => 0
            [d] => 102971157
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 1
            [d] => 167903564
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 2
            [b] => 4
            [c] => 4
            [d] => 1894248447
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 3
            [b] => 6
            [c] => 9
            [d] => 929037839
        )

)
```

And the JSON output

```
[
  {"a":0,"b":0,"c":0,"d":102971157},
  {"a":1,"b":2,"c":1,"d":167903564},
  {"a":2,"b":4,"c":4,"d":1894248447},
  {"a":3,"b":6,"c":9,"d":929037839}
]
```

---

EDIT

> how I could order my array by attribute b?

First create two reusable comparators

```
function ascendingComparator($a, $b) {
  if ($a > $b)      return 1;
  else if ($a < $b) return -1;
  else              return 0;
}

function descendingComparator($a, $b) {
  return -1 * ascendingComparator($a, $b);
}
```

Then use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to pass the `b` property into the comparator

```
// sort ascending; lowest b value will be first in the array
usort($objects, function($x, $y) {
  return ascendingComparator($x->b, $y->b);
});
echo json_encode($objects);

// OR sort descending; highest b value will be first in the array
usort($objects, function($x, $y) {
  return descendingComparator($x->b, $y->b);
});
echo json_encode($objects);
```

Comment: Thanks!! And then how I could order my array by attribute b ?

Comment: What type of value is `b`? An integer?

Comment: Yes, is an integer

Comment: @LigaVirtualF1 I've added information on how to sort